# Is it possible to override naviox-users. properties file in production environment

Tags: authentication, openxava

For an initial pilot of a small app, I would like to keep a separate file for users name/passwords to be used in dev environment, and one for the prd environment.

Up to now, I have two files, and I copy manually the prd one to naviox-users.properties before creating the war.

Can you suggest a better strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to redefine your createWar Ant target in the build.xml of your project, so it copies the production naviox-users files when creating the war. Something like this:

```
<target name="createWar">
    <ant antfile="${openxava.base.dir}/OpenXava/build.xml" target="prepareWar"/>
    <copy file="../${project.name}/properties/naviox-users-for-production.properties" 
        toFile="../${project.name}/${classes.dir}/naviox-users.properties" 
        overwrite="yes"/>
    <jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/${name.war}.war" basedir="web"/>
</target>
```

I didn't test the above code, it's just to give you a clue.

Comment: I have tested it, and works perfectly